# Error defining a binary tree when using mypy

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I'm using Python 3.5 and I want to use [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) to enable static type checking. But I have errors when I try to define a  binary tree:

```
class BinaryTreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value, left: BinaryTreeNode=None, right:BinaryTreeNode=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

Error message:

```
NameError: name 'BinaryTreeNode' is not defined
```

It seems mypy is not able to use a class before the class is defined, right?

Answer (score 2):

For earlier versions of Mypy (like the one you were probably using when you wrote this question), that's right. In order to use the name of a class as a type within the definition of the class, you'd have to enclose the name of the class in quotes, like this:

```py
class BinaryTreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value, left: 'BinaryTreeNode'=None, right:'BinaryTreeNode'=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

However, this should be fixed in newer version of Mypy. (Your code works as-is with Mypy 0.2.)